# How to display menu from database in a JSF template

Tags: jsf, java-ee-6

I want to display menu in JSF template. Every user of my application has different menu and the menu is stored in database. Here is my code,

MenuBean.java

```
public List<Menuitem> getUserMenu() {
    List<Menuitem> menuitems = (List<Menuitem>) em.createQuery("_____________").setParameter("_______", _______).getResultList();
    return menuitems;
}
```

pageTemplate.xhtml

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <ui:repeat var="_item" value="#{menuitemBean.userMenu}">
                <li><h:outputLink value="#{_item.url}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{_item.name}" />
                    </h:outputLink></li>
            </ui:repeat>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <h1>
            <ui:insert name="header" />
        </h1>
        <h2>
            <ui:insert name="subheader" />
        </h2>

        <ui:insert name="main" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Problem is each time I navigate to a new page (.xhtml file) which is using the same template (pageTemplate.xhtml) the menu is loading all over again.

How can I load the menu only once per user.

Answer (score 4):

If the menu is dependent on the user, it would be better to create a bean with a scope `session` that will store the content of this menu.
This way, once the menu is initialized the first time, it will not be re-initialized. Your code will look like that:

```
public class MySessionBean ... {

    private List<Menuitem> menuItems = null;

    public List<Menuitem> getUserMenu() {
        if (menuItems == null) {
            // Initialize the menu items.
            menuItems = ...;
        }
        return menuitems;
    }
```

Note that you can also initialize the `menuItems` objects in the constructor, or in a `post-construct` method (i.e. a method called just after the bean is instantiated).

An important thing also : do not put database access code in your beans (your `em.createQuery(...)`). Move that on service / DAO layers, and let the bean call the service to retrieve the information needed to build the menu items.

Comment: Thank you, I've added the database access in the method, just to simplify the question posted here. Implemented in the way suggested.

Comment: @Latte ok. Does it answers your question?

Answer (score 2):

You should **NOT** put logic accessing the database in a getter method, because [they are often called more than once in the same request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times).

To load your menu once for each user, put the property in a `@SessionScoped` backing bean and then initialize it in a `@PostConstruct` annotated method:

```
@SessionScoped
public SomeBean {
    private List<Menuitem> menuItems;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        menuItems = (List<Menuitem>) em.createQuery("_____________")
                           .setParameter("_______", _______).getResultList();
    }
    // getter and setter for menuItems
}
```

As the bean is in the session scope, it will exist as one instance for each user session in your application.

*Note that I assumed you are using JSF 2, because you tagged the question as [java-ee-6](/questions/tagged/java-ee-6).*